# Attempting to change Cloud CDN cache mode to "Use origin settings ..." causes error "Invalid value for field 'resource.cdnPolicy.defaultTtl': '0'"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a *Backend service* for which I would like to change the *Cloud CDN* "Cache mode".

The current setting is "Force cache all content". This looks as follows: [image: Force cache all content]

When I attempt to change it to "Use origin settings based on Cache-Control headers": [image: Use origin settings based on Cache-Control headers]

I get the error `Invalid value for field 'resource.cdnPolicy.defaultTtl': '0'. default_ttl cannot be specified with USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS cache_mode.`: [image: Invalid value for field 'resource.cdnPolicy.defaultTtl': '0']

How do I solve this?

**EDIT:** It’s a GCP bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183625573

Comment: Can you provide reproduction steps for the entire service? I tried to set up similar CDN but did not encounter any errors.

Comment: I reported the bug to GCP and forgot all about this question. Here’s the issue tracker link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183625573

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug on the frontend? I was able to fix it from the command line with:

`gcloud beta compute backend-services update [backend_name_here] --global --cache-mode=USE_ORIGIN_HEADERS`

You can find `backend_name_here` at the top of the page in your screenshot. For me, it was in the format `k8s-be-...-...`

**Note**: I added `--global` because the backend service could not be found without this parameter. If your backend service has a specific region, you probably don't want to use this (you might need to use `--region`).

More info: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update

Comment: GCP has acknowledged that it’s a bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183625573. Your answer may be a valid workaround.

Comment: Is there an update on this? - Clicking on the issue tracker link returns an "Access Denied"